# Dynamic NSPredicate in SwiftUI - Why does it has to be encapsulated?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

There are a lot great tutorials out there, how to dynamically alter the predicate of a fetchRequest like [this one](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui). They all do have in common, that the predicate (e.g. the search string) is passed into a second view which encapsulates the fetch-request and handles displaying the results.

Although I have nothing against the concept of encapsulating large views into smaller ones, I'd like to understand, why the following won't work instead:

```
// !! NOT WORKING EXAMPLE !!
struct SerachView: View {
    
    @State private var search: String = ""
    
    var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<ItemEntity> {
        FetchRequest<ItemEntity>(entity: ItemEntity.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", search)).wrappedValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $search)
            .padding()
        
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(fetchRequest.wrappedValue, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item.name ?? "n/a")")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because from my understanding, the computed property should produce a different fetchRequest ehenever the search string changes which then again should cause the ForEach to re-render. However it does not show any.

Comment: The computed property will show a new request every time it is accessed not when the `@State` is changed.

Comment: @lorem ipsum well that's what I thought too. But add a print statement befor the return in the computet property. It will print every time the $search state changes. Also because it's a computed property shouldn't it be 'permanently' requested by the ForEach and thus re-compute whenever the $search state changes? Tht's at least what it seems to do, expect that fetchRequest.wrappedValue stays empty (.count = 0) and nothing is shown.

Comment: That is likely because this is the wrapper fetch request then. Maybe if you use NSFetchRequest